# Ayuda con el recorrido de solo una columna de una matriz(Python)

Tags: python

como están todos. El día de hoy tengo una duda y es en como puedo recorrer estrictamente la columna uno de una matriz, con el fin de buscar en esa columna una coincidencia con un valor ingresado por parámetro y una vez cumplida esa condición(Qué algún elemento de esa columna sea igual al ingresado por parámetro), sume todos los elementos de la fila correspondiente a esa columna y retornar al final un entero(Que corresponde al resultado de esa suma). Espero puedan ayudarme, gracias.

Aquí el encabezado de la función descrita anteriormente(Como pueden ver la matriz que usaré para este fin entra como parámetro y el valor el cual se va a buscar como coincidencia corresponde al de facultad):

```
def puestos_atendidos(puestos: list, facultad: str)-> int:
```

Comment: Hola, comenta qué has intentado hasta ahora, qué problema tienes para continuar

Comment: He estado viendo, y recorrer la columna 1 es muy similar a recorrer la matriz completa, solamente que el segundo índice se mantiene en 0. Para encontrar la facultad se puede con un condicional y una vez la encuentre, ahí debería aumentar el segundo índice pero manteniendo el primer índice e ir sumando los valores que se encuentran ahí. Pero no sé como hacer eso :(

Answer (score 0):

Para recorrer una matriz tan solo tienes que recorrerlo con un bucle for, donde el índice del bucle sea la columna de la matriz. (Léase la aclaración sobre matrices más abajo si la necesitara).

Ten en cuenta que el método `puestos_atendidos` recibe una `list` y una `string`. Deberás hacer el cambio de `string` a `int` para poder comparar.

En el `main()` le pasamos la matriz y un número en string.

```py
import numpy as np 
matriz = np.array([
    [1, 2, 3],
    [4, 5, 6],
    [7, 8, 9]
])

def main():
    puestos_atendidos(matriz, '1')

def puestos_atendidos(puestos: list, facultad: str)-> int:
    numero = int(facultad) #Conversión string a int

    for i in range(0,3):
        if(puestos[i][0] == facultad):
            print((puestos[i][0] + puestos[i][1] + puestos[i][2]))
            break
```

Se ha implementado el `for i in range(0,3)` que itera desde 0 a 2, que es exactamente el tamaño que tiene nuestro array bidimensional.

Teniendo la coincidencia de la columna, es fácil sumar la fila ya sustituyes el valor de las filas de la matriz.

## Matrices

Es importante que tengas en cuenta que una matriz es **bidimensional**. Esto quiere decir que para recorrerlo debes operarlo teniendo en cuenta las **columnas** y **filas**. Siempre empezando desde el valor 0.

En el ejemplo que te he puesto si quieres obtener el número **5** sería la posición `[1][1]`. Porque es la columna 2 y fila 2.

Espero dejar claro algunos conceptos. Si no entiendes algo del código te lo aclaro sin problema.